# RestSharp - Different UTC offset for different years when deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, json, datetime, restsharp

I have a JSON with datetime fields to deserialize. But the UTC offset for parsed datetime differes for different years. Example:

```
["Date":"2015-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00"]  ->  01/01/2015 03:00:00 AM
```

While date for other year is parsed with other offset

```
["Date":"2005-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00"]  ->  01/01/2005 02:00:00 AM
```

I've also checked actual offset for my time zone, and it returns same offset for both those years

```
TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(2015) -> 03:00:00
TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(2005) -> 03:00:00
```

Could someone please explain why that is so? How can I bypass it?

My time zone is UTC(+03:00) Minsk

Comment: Time zone rules for Russia changed in 2014. `CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset()` can't give you the correct offset for an individual date. Your date/time value is likely correct when converted to local time -- if you don't want the local time, use `.ToUniversalTime()` first.

Comment: It helped, thanks a lot :)